# Zoom Hover Effect inin 7 separate iscolated areas within one image map

Tags: javascript, css, image, zooming, effect

How can I create a Zoom Hover Effect in 7 separate spots within one image map image? I have one image map with 7 Hotspots in the image. I need to make each hotspot zoom in when hovering over it without effecting the rest of the hotspots or image, and also not to comprimise hyperlink.

Can anyone teach me?

Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is about helping software development, please provide code example of what you've tried or the efforts you did, and the difficulties you face.

Comment: To use a metaphor; If you're asking for directions to the White House, we need to know where you're starting from to be able to help you.